# "column-span" not working on table which is created by div

Tags: html, css

I have created table structure using div. I need to add column-span on "No Data Found" div but it is not working in my case. Please check below fiddle which is in comment. I want red background in 100% of width.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.tHead {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.tBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.td,
.th {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.no-data-found {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  column-span: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="tHead">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="th">
        Heading 1
      </div>
      <div class="th">
        Heading 2
      </div>
      <div class="th">
        Heading 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tBody">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td no-data-found">
        No Data Found
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/koradiyakinjan/btmch9nw/3/

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and put a snippet we can run into your question. Also describe what not working means in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) layout:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
}

.no-data-found {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Heading 1</div>
  <div>Heading 2</div>
  <div>Heading 3</div>
  <div class="no-data-found">No Data Found</div>
</div>
```

**Note**: The attributes `colspan` and `rowspan` can be used only with `<th>` and `<td>` elements. You can, however, achieve the effect you want with positioning if you insist on using a `table` display:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.colspan {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Heading 1</div>
    <div class="cell">Heading 2</div>
    <div class="cell">Heading 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="colspan">No Data Found</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't use grid layout as project is already developed.

Comment: @KinjanKoradiya: See the update.